# How to have a view draggable until it becomes full height then make it scrollable?

Tags: java, android

so I am having a bit of a predicament. I have created an activity which functions like a bottom sheet. One feature that many of my users have asked for is the ability to make it so once the bottom sheet is fully extended, the sheet will then scroll so they can view the rest of the items. I tried putting my linear layout inside of a nestedscrollview but that just caused a crash. Please do not recommend me to use the support bottom sheet class as that does not have everything I need for it to work. Thank you in advance!

Here is the layout for the bottom sheet:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/totalScreen"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
    android:gravity="bottom|center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sheetTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#424242"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:text="Dummy Title"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/sheetTitle"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-28dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:fabSize="normal" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/sheetScreen"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/sheetTitle"
        android:background="#424242"
        android:gravity="bottom|center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp">

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the ontouch listener which allows the bottom sheet behavior:

```
ID: 
protected LinearLayout main;
protected RelativeLayout full;

protected void setAdjustableTouchListener() {
        full.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        mDragStartY = event.getY();
                        mPointerOffset = event.getRawY() + main.getMeasuredHeight();
                        return true;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:                        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
                        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
                        int sheetHeight = (int) (metrics.heightPixels - event.getY());
                        if (mDragStartY < (event.getY() + TAP_DRIFT_TOLERANCE) && mDragStartY > (event.getY() - TAP_DRIFT_TOLERANCE)
                                && ((SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - mDraggingStarted) < SINGLE_TAP_MAX_TIME)
                                && sheetHeight > (main.getMeasuredHeight() + findViewById(R.id.sheetTitle).getMeasuredHeight())) {
                            result = "Dismissed";
                            finish();
                        } else {
                            if (main.getMeasuredHeight() > (viewConversion + heightDifference)) {
                                ResizeAnimation a = new ResizeAnimation(main);
                                a.setDuration(500);
                                a.setParams(main.getMeasuredHeight(), extendedViewHeight);
                                main.startAnimation(a);
                                state = 2;
                            } else if (main.getMeasuredHeight() < (viewConversion + heightDifference)
                                    && main.getMeasuredHeight() > viewConversion) {
                                ResizeAnimation a = new ResizeAnimation(main);
                                a.setDuration(500);
                                a.setParams(main.getMeasuredHeight(), viewConversion);
                                main.startAnimation(a);
                                state = 1;
                            } else if (main.getMeasuredHeight() < viewConversion && main.getMeasuredHeight() > (viewConversion / 2)) {
                                ResizeAnimation a = new ResizeAnimation(main);
                                a.setDuration(500);
                                a.setParams(main.getMeasuredHeight(), viewConversion);
                                main.startAnimation(a);
                                state = 1;
                            } else if (main.getMeasuredHeight() < (viewConversion / 2)) {
                                result = "Dismissed";
                                finish();
                            }
                        }
                        return true;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        if (mPointerOffset - event.getRawY() < extendedViewHeight)
                            setPrimaryContentHeight((int) (mPointerOffset - event.getRawY()));
                        return true;
                    default:
                        return true;
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Here is the method to actually set the new height of the sheet:

```
protected boolean setPrimaryContentHeight(int newHeight) {
    // the new primary content height should not be less than 0 to make the
    // handler always visible
    newHeight = Math.max(0, newHeight);
    // the new primary content height should not be more than the SplitView
    // height minus handler height to make the handler always visible
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) main.getLayoutParams();
    if (newHeight >= 0) {
        params.height = newHeight;
        // set the primary content parameter to do not stretch anymore and
        // use the height specified in the layout params
    }
    main.setLayoutParams(params);
    return true;
}
```

Here is the crash that occurs when using the NestedScrollView:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.nick.mowen.sceneplugin/com.nick.mowen.sceneplugin.ui.BottomSheetActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #32: Binary XML file line #32: Error inflating class android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2450)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2520)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1363)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5466)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #32: Binary XML file line #32: Error inflating class android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:267)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:129)
at com.nick.mowen.sceneplugin.ui.BottomSheetActivity.onCreate(BottomSheetActivity.java:37)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2403)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2520) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1363) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5466) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #32: Error inflating class android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:267) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:129) 
at com.nick.mowen.sceneplugin.ui.BottomSheetActivity.onCreate(BottomSheetActivity.java:37) 
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251) 
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2403) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2520) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1363) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5466) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:267) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:129) 
at com.nick.mowen.sceneplugin.ui.BottomSheetActivity.onCreate(BottomSheetActivity.java:37) 
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251) 
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2403) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2520) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1363) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5466) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v4.view.NestedScrollingChildHelper.setNestedScrollingEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference
at android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(NestedScrollView.java:212)
at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:4256)
at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:573)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.<init>(FrameLayout.java:97)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.<init>(FrameLayout.java:92)
at android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView.<init>(NestedScrollView.java:189)
at android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView.<init>(NestedScrollView.java:185)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:267) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:129) 
at com.nick.mowen.sceneplugin.ui.BottomSheetActivity.onCreate(BottomSheetActivity.java:37) 
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251) 
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2403) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2520) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1363) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5466) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: I'm wondering: what is it that the new bottom sheet from the Support library doesn't have, so you can't use that instead?
Also, another solution instead of using a custom touchlistener, would be to use a `ListView` with an invisible header item, that is the same height as the screen. Then when the headerview disappears (is scrolled out of the view) you remove the header view or collapse it by setting it to gone. I've used this method for having 2 fragments on top of each other - it works pretty nicely.

Comment: I have it so my users can add things like an FAB to the top of the view. That gets cut off, also things like being able to drag from anywhere, and tap above to dismiss, and dimming the background, etc. I ended up just putting a recyclerview in place of the LinearLayout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, solved this, what I ended up doing was just adding a recyclerview in place of the linearlayout. Then I just made the LayoutManager overridden so it is only scrollable when I set it to be:

```
main.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this) {
            @Override
            public boolean canScrollVertically() {
                return canScroll && super.canScrollVertically();
            }
        });
```